# create-react-app npm run start in production mode. Maybe not possible?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-router, create-react-app

I need to run the server like I simply do with:

`npm run start`

but I need to use the production mode. Is this possible?

In ember or angular it is possible. How to do in `create-react-app`?

I tried `npm run start --prod` but nothing.

Comment: in react you cant , the only thing you can do is to npm run build

Comment: As per github readme (https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/README.md#getting-started) of create-react-app, npm run build is the command to build the app in production mode. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: No @sunil, I need to develop in production mode directly.

Comment: i am a bit curiouse why you need to devolop on a build mod ?

Comment: @AbdeslemCharif I want to run in production build in my development environment for testing and profiling purposes. With non-CRA React I'd just change to build in Production mode and it'd be good to go. Maybe OP wants the same.

Answer (score 52):

The best option is probably to do a normal production build and then run it locally.

First install an HTTP server:

```
npm install serve -g
```

Then:

```
npm run build
serve -s build
```

By default, it will run on port 5000 so your local URL is
http://localhost:5000

Comment: Worked like chram. Thank you

Answer (score 7):

To serve the app in production mode you need to follow below steps

1. create a production build

   npm run build
2. install [npm serve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve/v/10.1.1) globally

   npm i -g serve
3. You may serve it with a static server now

   serve -s build

You can check for more options [here](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/available-scripts#npm-run-build).

For the development in production you can enable Hot reloading in react app without ejecting

With just 3 lines of code, you can turn on HMR, but with one big caveat: React state and DOM state are not preserved between reloads. This is kind of a bummer.

You can add these lines to index.js to turn on standard Webpack HMR that doesn’t preserve state between reloads:

```
if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept();
}
```

Read more about it [here](https://medium.com/@brianhan/hot-reloading-cra-without-eject-b54af352c642) Hope it helps Thanks!

Answer (score -12):

Yes you can run `npm start` command on server but there should be your ***node-modules***. If ***node-modules*** are not present there than you can get them with `npm install` command.

Comment: You didn't understand my question.